# Rock, paper, Scissors (python 3.3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i'm making a rock paper scissors game and i have made the following script so far:

```
def main():
    from random import randint
    UserChoices = input("'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors'? \n Input: ")
    if UserChoices == "rock":
        UserChoice = 1
    elif UserChoices == "paper":
        UserChoice = 2
    elif UserChoices == "scissors":
        UserChoice = 3
    CpuChoice = randint(1,3) 
    if UserChoice == CpuChoice:
        print("DRAW!")
    elif UserChoice == "1" and CpuChoice== "3":
        print("Rock beats scissors PLAYER WINS!")
        main()
    elif UserChoice == "3" and CpuChoice== "1":
        print("Rock beats scissors CPU WINS")
        main()
    elif UserChoice == "1" and CpuChoice== "2":
        print("Paper beats rock CPU WINS!")
        main()
    elif UserChoice == "2" and CpuChoice== "1":
        print("paper beats rock PLAYER WINS!")
        main()
    elif UserChoice == "2" and CpuChoice== "3":
        print("Scissors beats paper CPU WINS!")
        main()
    elif UserChoice == "3" and CpuChoice== "2":
        print("Scissors beats paper PLAYER WINS!")
        main()
    elif UserChoice == "1" and CpuChoice== "2":
        print("cpu wins")
        main()
    else:
        print("Error: outcome not implemented")
main()
```

but when I run it I get the error I made "Error: outcome not implemented" Can someone tell me why this is? thank you.

Comment: `UserChoice` and `CpuChoice` are set to integers and you're then comparing them to strings.

Comment: in the else, do a print of the values and you'll se why

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but I suggest you map the ramdom numbers to string instead of the other way around.

Comment: As a matter of style, it is preferred that you write variables as `user_choice` and `cpu_choice` in Python.  The `CamelCase` scheme is typically reserved for class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This and all the other comparisons similar to it:

```
elif UserChoice == "1" and CpuChoice == "3":
```

... should be:

```
elif UserChoice == 1 and CpuChoice == 3:
```

In other words, you should be comparing `int`s with `int`s, instead of `int`s with strings as is happening right now.

Comment: Thanks can't believe it was something as simple as that!

Answer (score 2):

User choice is set to an integer, however you compare it to a string. It should be as follows

```
if userChoice == 1: #Note no quotation marks
```

Also, you are allowing the CPU to choose from 3 integers, which works. However, it may save lines and be more efficient to choose a random from an array

```
CPU_Moves = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
cpuchoice = random.choice(CPUMoves)
```

This will set `cpuchoice` to one of the random from the array, and you can then use it in the comparison of user input to the `cpuchoice`. This would mean you wouldn't need to set `userChoice` at all, you could use what the user enters directly.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers say, you ended up comparing a string against an integer.
It would be a good idea to avoid using so many conditionals. Here's a "compact version" I've written, in case you're interested:

```
from random import randrange

def RPS(user_choice = ''):
    choices = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')
    results = ('Draw!', 'You Win!', 'Cpu Wins!')
    while user_choice not in choices:
        user_choice = input("Choose: rock, paper or scissors? ")
    user_num = choices.index(user_choice)
    cpu_num = randrange(3)
    diff = (user_num - cpu_num) % 3
    print("You chose:", user_choice, "-", "Cpu chose:", choices[cpu_num])
    print(results[diff])

RPS('rock')  # User choice can be passed as an argument.
```

Notice how you can calculate the winner with a subtraction and a modulo operation. This is even more useful in a Rock, paper, scissors, lizzard, Spock game, where you have 5 choices instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes from your if else statement. the conditionals are looking for a string to compare while rock paper and scissors are assigned as integers. these are not handled the same way. you need to change your if elif to not have quotes around the numbers. it prints out DRAW because its comparing like items and it give and error because it is not the same variable type.